# CXF dependency error on Websphere Portal 8.5

Tags: java, spring, maven, cxf, websphere-portal

So I have to deploy portlet with a web service client using CXF into Websphere Portal 8.5.

When I deploy, I'm getting a MethodNotFound exception.

According to many Google searches, this has to be fixed changing the server configuration to PARENT LAST, in order for the portal to use the application's Maven dependencies before trying to use Websphere's.

The dependency error is gone, but now I get the following:

```
[10/19/15 16:18:13:028 CDT] 00000076 AppManagement W   CWWMA0116W: Unable to start: my-portlet-ear using: WebSphere:name=ApplicationManager,process=WebSphere_Portal,platform=proxy,node=MW7KLKW11BC671Node,version=8.5.5.0,type=ApplicationManager,mbeanIdentifier=ApplicationManager,cell=MW7KLKW11BC671Cell,spec=1.0 exception is: javax.management.MBeanException: Exception thrown in RequiredModelMBean while trying to invoke operation startApplication
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1303)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1092)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl._startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1482)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl.startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1371)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl.startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1320)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:291)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1260)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:300)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1254)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1092)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.rmi.RMIConnectorService.invoke(RMIConnectorService.java:282)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.rmi._RMIConnectorService_Tie.invoke(_RMIConnectorService_Tie.java:395)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.rmi._RMIConnectorService_Tie._invoke(_RMIConnectorService_Tie.java:160)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:678)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:525)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:616)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1581)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doRequestWork(Connection.java:3140)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:3010)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:64)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: null
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:432)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1175)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:774)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1374)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2179)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:663)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5474)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5600)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:677)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:621)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1266)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:291)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1260)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:300)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1254)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: null
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:759)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: null
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:176)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:746)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:154)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebAppImpl.java:613)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:409)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
    ... 76 more
```

The root exception gives me no information about what is wrong about my dependencies.

I know that the problem is not in my server because we deployed another portlet which also uses CFX's client and it works (I tried to use that project's POM as a base, but ultimately, I get the same exception).

I have checked the dependency tree and I don't see any conflict in the dependencies. The application was working correctly, but using the PARENT FIRST configuration.

Do you have any idea on how can I fix this exception?

I'm using the following versions:

```
<spring.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.security.version>3.1.7.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
<slf4j-version>1.7.5</slf4j-version>
<jackson.version>1.5.0</jackson.version>
<cxf.version>2.4.6</cxf.version>
<servlet-api-version>2.4</servlet-api-version>
<jasypt.version>1.9.0</jasypt.version>
<ojdbc.version>12.1.0.1.0</ojdbc.version>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was on my Spring version. I had another POM which is parent to my Websphere project, and that POM had different Spring versions.